# Reading by Thread and Ploting by Timer in C#

Tags: multithreading, timer, locking, monitor

I trying to Read Data from three Sensors and Plot their Values. For Reading I'm using Thread and for Ploting I'm using a 50ms Timer. for each sensor, I have a List to store data in it.
my code like this:

```
    List<double> a1 = new List<double>();
    List<double> a2 = new List<double>();
    List<double> a3 = new List<double>();
    private readonly object _Lock = new object();
    private bool _proceesFlag = true;
    private Thread AnalogInputThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(AnalogSequences));
    private void AnalogSequences()
    {
        while (_proceesFlag)
        {
            Monitor.Enter(_Lock);
            try
            {
                a1.Add(ReadAnalogSensor1());
                a2.Add(ReadAnalogSensor1());
                a3.Add(ReadAnalogSensor1());

            }
            catch (SynchronizationLockException exception)
            {

            }

            finally
            {
                Monitor.Exit(_Lock);
            }
        }
    }
    private int lastIndex = 0;
    private void DrawTime_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lock (_Lock)
        {

            for (int i = lastIndex; i < a1.Count; i++)
            {
                Plot(a1[i], a2[i], a3[i]);
                lastIndex = a1.Count;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

I want to Know is this method is a good way for sharing object between Thread and Timer?
or i'm doing wrong code and I should use another method?